# Как задать переменной свойство чтения на php?

Tags: php

Как заставить переменную принять заданный текст в процессе работы?

Например: `'Погода в $переменная_которая_примет_текст'`

Comment: `"Погода в {$name}"`

Comment: Или `'Погода в '.$name`